# Table background image cutoff when using nowrap

Tags: html, css

I am trying to keep a line of text in a cell from moving down to the next line, but when using `white-space: nowrap;` the image background that previously covered 100% of the screen is cutoff, as seen in this screenshot:

before and after:

[image]

This is the code for the background:

```
div.transbox {
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-image: url('http://almosthome2016.org/images/header_trans_bg.png');
}
```

and the html for the table:

```
<div class="transbox"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="3%" align="left" valign="bottom"></td>
<td align="left" valign="bottom" class="style74"><span class="style8">ALMOST  HOME</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="style75">THE CAMPAIGN FOR THE NEW IRISH ARTS CENTER</span></td>
<td align="left" valign="bottom" class="style75">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

This was my way of getting the opaque background as the back of the table. I'm open to other suggestions if that is what is causing the issue with the nowrap.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
background-size:cover;
```

To your CSS for **div.transbox**